# I am getting an error 'block in install_default_gem' when install ruby using rbenv on WSL

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

icarus@DESKTOP-1HC4USL:/mnt/c/Users/K$ rbenv install 2.7.1
Downloading ruby-2.7.1.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.7/ruby-2.7.1.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.7.1...

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 20.04 using ruby-build 20200520-12-g69ccbf4)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20200704033744.16541.pfVhNf
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20200704033744.16541.log

Last 10 log lines:
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:846:in `block (2 levels) in install_default_gem' from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:279:in` open_for_install'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:845:in `block in install_default_gem' from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:835:in` each'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:835:in `install_default_gem' from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:799:in` block in '
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:950:in `block in <main>' from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:947:in` each'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:947:in `'
make: *** [uncommon.mk:373: do-install-all] Error 1

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. The log you posted looks like just the middle of a stack trace. Look further up in the log to see the error type and message and edit your question to include that.

Comment: https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1752 ?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have installed the dependencies for ruby.

https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/wiki#suggested-build-environment

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf bison build-essential libssl-dev libyaml-dev libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libffi-dev libgdbm6 libgdbm-dev libdb-dev
```

Some libraries might be missing in different Ubuntu versions.
In my case, libgdbm6 was not found on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Your advice seems helpful. What is the significance of the link?

Comment: ```sudo apt-get install autoconf bison build-essential libssl-dev libyaml-dev libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libffi-dev libgdbm6 libgdbm-dev libdb-dev```

You can use this command

Comment: Is that supposed to be an answer to the question about the significance of the link? Does not seem like one to me.

Comment: Can you explain the reason for providing the link here? I believe that the code you show works and that the general advice is sound. But I do not see why you provide a link without explaining what the link is linking to and what it provides to this answer.

Comment: Or to put it differently, I do not click on links to find out what is there. I want to be told what is there before I do so. Please consider to write something like "Here I link to some pretty pictures of my adorable kitten."